# Firebase Functions Emulator ignores environment variables in .env file, prompts "Enter a string value for {ENV_KEY}"

Tags: firebase, environment-variables, firebase-tools

After upgrading Firebase CLI tools to version 11.15.0 (needed for NodeJS 18), my local Firebase Emulator ignores the environment variables defined in `./functions/.env` or `./functions/.env.dev` (when `dev` is aliased to the project ID).

```
firebase emulators:start
```

...prompts me to:

```
"Enter a string value for {ENV_KEY}: "
```

...even if that environment variable is defined in `.env`.

Piping env vars into emulator stops it from happening:

```
env $(cat ./functions/.env) | firebase emulators:start
```

On a previous version the same `.env` file worked fine. I have tried adding an alias, with same results. Secrets in `./functions/.secret.local` (same format as .env) are being picked up.

Why is the Firebase Emulator ignoring my `.env` file or this is a regression?